# How does this person have 127K rep?

Tags: support, area-51

If you see the [Language Learning proposal,](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) and total user rep, then the first thing that pops up is:

[image: bug]

Obviously, the person only has 27K total rep.

Comment: Total rep is the user's own rep + the rep of any users they've referred. That user referred Tom Au with 99.6k rep.

Comment: I am 5th there. I referred 4 people, total rep amounting to 80k.  Pretty cool feature it is though :)

Comment: Dang, I totally thought that freehand is the first cool thing in Area51 design.

Comment: Love how this question has more votes than the duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you hover over the "total reputation" tab, you can see that it says

> Committers with the highest reputation including users they have referred

Meaning that the "total rep" displayed is the sum of both their reputation and the reputation of everybody that they referred.